# Android Fragment and RecyclerView , ViewHolder , Adapter

Tags: android

how to add a **RecyclerView** to a **Fragment** together with its **Adapter** and **ViewHolder** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you would for an activity. Create the adapter object and pass the necessary data to it's constructor and then pass this adapter object to the recyclerview with setAdapter(adapter).

Comment: Do you mind adding code sample Please ! i am new to android .thanks a lot

Comment: Check out this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ 
It works the same way in a fragment as it does for an activity.